# Can you send sub-sequential HTTP POST request to a sever

Tags: vb.net, http-post, web-scraping

I'm just getting started in HTTP POST requests. So much so that I've got no idea if this is even going to solve my problem, but it seems like an interesting thing to learn about either way. Anyway, I currently do the following with a webbrowser control:

1. Navigate to a page
2. Enter username and password
3. Click the 'login' button
4. Enter some text into textboxes
5. Click another button (which loads a confirm page)
6. Click the confirm button

My question is does the HTTP POST request thing allow for the webclient to stay logged into the webpage, does it allow for posting to the page and then posting again once the update page has been received (steps 4, 5 and 6).

Comment: every http request is independent of every other http request - it's a stateless protocol. you can do whatever sequence of HTTP requests you want. post->get->put->delete->head->post->blah->blah->blah.

Comment: @MarcB So I could in theory do steps 1-6 all in one http request? Great! Also since I actually do steps 1-3 and then repeat steps 4-6 many times would I be best doing that in one request? Or is it bad to keep the http request 'open'?

Comment: there's http keepalives, but only for short durations, because the server does NOT want to have its resources exhausted. generally speaking you connection, do/request something, disconnect.

Comment: Ah OK. Well that's actually my question answered. If you'd like to drop everything you've said into an answer, I'll make it as the correct answer and this questions can be 'answered' :) Also do you no of any tutorials where there do a lot of stuff in one request?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you want to scrape some web content or manipulate a site from a program or script, but you're having a hard time. No, just switching to a POST will not help you here. Often, the problem has to do with authentication. What you need to do is preserve your **session** across more than one HTTP **request**, whether the requests are POST, GET, HEAD, DELETE, PUT, UPDATE, etc.

As mentioned in a comment, HTTP requests are *stateless*, where each request is independent of the others. However, web servers will still maintain some information for individual sessions, and so you usually still need more than one request. However, I find that much of the time, exactly two requests are enough to accomplish an action on a web site.

The first request will POST your login information to the site. At this point, the web site will issue a **response**. You need to analyze this response, because somewhere in there will be a session key. Now when I tell you to analyze the response, I don't mean that you write code to do this... that will come later. You need to actually send a sample request record the response, and read through it with your own eyes to find the session key. You also need to know how the web server expects to find the session key on future requests.

In this process, it's important to remember that a response consists of more than just HTML. In fact, the most common location for this key is in a **cookie**. Once you know how to get the session key, you need to make sure your next request includes that session key as part of the request. This is how the web site will know who you are, that you are authorized to perform the desired action, and what information to return.

The second request will actually perform the desired action. This could be a simple GET request, if all you want to do is retrieve some information from the site. It may also be POST, if you need to tell the site to perform some action.

To know what your requests need to look like, you can use a special kind of http proxy. **[Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/)** is a popular choice. You install the proxy to your computer, and then perform the desired action from a regular web browser. Fiddler will then tell you what requests and responses were sent. Even if you need to view a number of pages to complete your action via your web browser, often you still only need the final request to actually accomplish your goal. You use the information provided by fiddler to find and duplicate the required requests.

In the .Net world, the best tool for sending these requests and evaluating the responses is generally **not** the WebBrowser control. Instead, take a look at the [`System.Net.WebClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx) class, or look at [`System.Net.HttpWebRequest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx)/[`System.Net.HttpWebResponse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebresponse.aspx).